# How to schedule an on-premise Azure DevOps build to run every 5 minutes?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

Never mind the rationale, I have a case where a build needs to run every 5 minutes. On-premise installation does not support schedules in the YAML.

So, how do we do it? I can probably use the REST Api, but that sucks, because it seems either I create a one-off script or a script for very simple type of schedules. Building a reusable solution, that could be used in general for other builds seems to be involved. So, instead of concentrating on my business I need to go sideways and cover for the deficiencies of the on-premise version of Azure DevOps.

I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: Use a non-YAML build, which **does** support schedules? I'd love to know what you need to build every 5 minutes on a schedule, though.

Comment: Have you seen the UI for non YAML build? You need to manually add every schedule event. In my case I would have to add 24*12=288 events. No can do.

Comment: (This build is actually sort of a watch dog. We are an on-premise shop, so I spinning a dedicated web service is expensive. The same goes for scheduled windows task - somebody needs to maintain it. And since it is inaccessible from outside, time driven Azure Functions are not helpful too)

Comment: Hi mark, just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. Sorry this is not supported. But if a feature (Yaml build with schedules) already released in azure devOps service, usually will also be included in next latest azure devops server/tfs release. However,  there isn't any better workaround at present. Do you still have any concern about this case?

Comment: Marked it as answer, sorry for the delay. It usually takes 6 months before features from the hosted version propagate to the on-premise and then it takes us time to upgrade it. In reality it means by the time it is available to us, we would have some adhoc awkward solution in place. And then it would take time to phase it out in favour of the natural solution. Net result - we are forced to waste time working around and then phasing out the work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand your concern. However, this is not supported at present with on-premise TFS sever.

The **UI for defining time-based build triggers** isn't flexible enough. It can **only support fixed times on days of the week**.

Just as you have pointed out in the comment, we have a need to run a build every 5 minutes which requires us to create 288 schedules which is tedious.

Actually, this has already been a user voice.

> *Scheduled builds - More flexible timing configuration*
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365630/scheduled-builds-more-flexible-timing-configuratio.html

Multiple persons commented and echoed. After go through the marketplace, haven't found a pretty appropriate workaround. Sorry for any inconvenience. You could monitor the status of above user voice.